# Why is my US English keyboard re-mapped to Swedish in MonoDevelop?

Tags: linux, keyboard, wine, input-languages, monodevelop

I am using Wine to run MonoDevelop and Unity in openSuSE and it works rather well. However, I have a snag where in MonoDevelop, my keyboard is mapped to use Swedish keyboard layout rather than my preferred layout, which is US English keyboard.

I have two physical keyboards connected to the computer. One is with Swedish layout and one is with US English layout. I switch between them as I need to. *It's the simplest way to use the US English keyboard layout, which I find is better than the Swedish layout.*

Worth noting is that it's only MonoDevelop that has this problem.

Does anyone knows why I get this kind of behaviour? That is, even though I am using the US English keyboard in MonoDevelop, it still maps it to Swedish keyboard layout?

Comment: I hope you don't mind my overhaul of your original post. I tried to preserve as much as possible of the original meaning. Am I right in that you have two physical keyboards connected to the computer?

Comment: What about other programs running in openSUSE? Do you have this problem there as well? How about other programs using Wine? Do you have more than one input source installed in openSUSE? What about language settings in MonoDevelop? Those are some of the things I would be looking at.

Comment: Hi I am sorry for any uncertainties in my question. I do **not** have two physical keyboards, I make use of two Keyboard maps (is that the correct term?) basically in my keyboard-settings I have set up one Swedish and one US English keyboard mapping. In everything BUT Mono Develop (under wine) this works, so Unity in wine works, and other software in wine works as well. So it must be related to monodevelop. I seem to have a problem using "force mono" (using winetricks) so it might be related, as I had to install dotnet4 to get monodevelop to work under wine. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that wine doesn't really listen to what mappings I've set in the OS, (using system settings), but rather looks at xkb. It kind of makes sense I just didn't think of it at first.

However, I can force it to US mapping which will in a small way solve my problem, however then I can't make use of SE layout. So I found out that I can make use of multiple layouts as such:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,se"
```

Which worked for me, now I can make use of the layouts also in monodevelop.